# Can one pass a variable via a GOTO or can one CALL but end w/o return?

Tags: batch-file

Let's say you have a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:part1
echo.
echo Part 1: Your Name
echo.
if "%1"=="err1" echo * You must supply a name! *&echo.
echo Please enter your name below.
echo.
set /p yourName=": "
if "%yourName%"=="" call :part1 err1
if /i "%yourName%"=="/q" goto :eof
goto :part2

:part2
echo.
echo Part 2: Your Age
echo.
if "%1"=="err1" echo * You must supply your age! *&echo.
echo Please enter your age below.
echo.
set /p yourAge=": "
if "%yourAge%"=="" call :part2 err1
if /i "%yourAge%"=="/q" goto :eof
goto :part3

:part3
echo.
echo Part 3: Your Favorite Number
echo.
if "%1"=="err1" echo * You must supply the number! *&echo.
echo Please enter your favorite number below.
echo.
set /p yourNum=": "
if "%yourNum%"=="" call :part3 err1
if /i "%yourNum%"=="/q" goto :eof
goto :part4

:part4
echo.
echo We're done!
echo.
echo Thanks %yourName%, I now know you are %yourAge% and like # %yourNum%!
goto :eof
```

I want to validate input and also be able to abort the process at each step.  It works grand; until someone screws up and triggers the validation.  I tried to goto :label err1 but GOTO doesn't allow passing parameters.  So I switched to CALL.  Problems are 1 it seems to retain %1 as it goes, because after I try to enter a blank name it yells at me to enter name.  I do, then on the next screen it immediately yells that I have to enter age though I didn't get a chance yet.  Second problem is if I try to terminate, goto :eof just closes the CALL loop and sends me back to where the CALL originated and it continues on.

What is the right way to handle this??  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To take your question title literally:

1. Can one pass a variable via a GOTO?
   No, you can't pass data via a `goto :label` use a variable.
2. can one CALL but end w/o return?
   No, a `goto :eof` or `exit /b` or implicit reaching the end of file in the called sub returns to the caller, but:

you can pass back an errorlevel and act upon that with

- conditional execution (`||` on fail / `&&` on success) or
- checking an `if errorlevel 1`.

---

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do call :Check %%i || goto :End
Echo Past for
:End
Echo Label End
pause
goto :Eof
:Check
Echo Check %1
if %1==5 Exit /B 1
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_50525014.cmd
Check 1
Check 2
Check 3
Check 4
Check 5
Label End
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your flow a bit.
And you should delete any variable you are using later with set /p, as set /p doesn't change the variable when the user press only enter

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :getName
if /i "%yourName%"=="/q" goto :eof
call :getAge
if /i "%yourAge%"=="/q" goto :eof
exit /b

:getName
echo(
echo Part 1: Your Name
echo(
echo Please enter your name below.
echo(
set "yourName="
set /p yourName=": "
if "%yourName%"=="" (
    echo * You must supply a name! *
    echo(
    goto :getName
)
exit /b

:getAge
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable and continue to work with it in a different part. That way you "kind-of" pass a variable to GOTO:

```
echo start
set foo=baa
GOTO part1

:part1
echo %foo%
GOTO end
```

The order does not matter, as long as you device `foo` before you use it.